# application run on iPhone 5 like it's in iPhone 4

Tags: ios, iphone, testflight

I know there are a few threads about this subject, but i saw that all of them refer to the fact that the launch image is not set properly.

In my app i don't use the launch image and create my own "launch image" process (an image view that runs for the length of the loading time). 
When i run the app with testfilght on the iPhone 4/6 all works well, but if I run the app on iPhone 5 the app runs like it's on an iPhone 4.

Thanks,

Comment: You MUST have the standard 4" launch image to support 4" devices like the iPhone 5/5s if your app supports iOS 7.x and earlier. For iOS 8 can you use the new launch screen file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add them using the .xassets easily. I have done a small test and I'm attaching a screenshot for your reference.

I haven't worked with iPhone 6. So, you may need to do some additions to get it to work correctly with iPhone 6.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

From my experience, iOS decides whether your application supports iPhone 5 from the height of the Default.png image.

You must have the following images for your app(For iPhone 4 and above)
a) Default.png (640x960 px)
b) Default-568h.png (640x1136 px)

Comment: Do i need to add them to my .xcassets folder? or just add them to my target?

Answer (score -1):

Use detect device but you must use two images.

```
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
            CGSize result = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
            if (result.height == 480) {
                //old iphone detected. 4 and above.
            }else{
                //New iPhone detected.
            }
        }
```